# Does a sidebar/navbar count towards columns in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 site and have a stupid question. The code I have (didn't write, cleaning up) has a sidebar navigation bar, which is nested under a container, but does *not* live within a col-div or row. Is this incorrect? The layout is currently:

```
<body>
  <section id="container"> (no class)
    <header/>
    <aside>
      <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
          <li class="sub-menu">
          ...
    </aside>
    <section id="main-content">
        <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
            <div>
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
                ...content...
```

Well, now that I condense it like this, I see that there is no *class* container anywhere in the hierarchy... Awesome! My original question remains, though:

Should a navigation sidebar exist within a col-*-* div, or next to that in the "content area"? I am thinking the former...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you'll have more than one `row`s then a tall column (containing the sidebar) would make the first `row` very high and thus break your design.

If what your designing is only one `row` high then you could put your sidebar within a `col-`.

In both situations though the best solution would be to **nest your grid elements** like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      ...Sidebar comes here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
          A nested grid can come here with it's own columns.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A great example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: "It depends" is more or less what I expected. That example is basically what I'm looking for, and it does include both the sidebar and "content" in the grid width calculation (2+10, 3+9). When the sidebar collapses, however, does that mean the remaining visible columns are recalculated (0+12), or the total is just no longer 12, yet it still works (maybe because it is a fluid container)?

Comment: Because the components (the sidebar and the content area) are Sutton 'col-'s themselves, when the sidebar collapses the right block which was 'col-md-8' in the example becomes 'col-md-12'

Comment: Correction: as the sidebar collapses on extra small screen size it would be rather 'col-xs-12'